# Examples of saving a built search and getting results that update?

Tags: search, search-results, save, faceted-search, alerts

I am trying to build a search that allows users to build and save their own specific search query which then auto populates with products that match this criteria (and keeps updating with new products that match the criteria without any input). For example, I would enter that I want results that match *Brown, *Leather, *Jacket, and see a list of brown leather jackets, and get email alerts every week (or whatever amount of time I specify) when there are new jackets in my list, as well as be able to see any new jackets matching my criteria when I log in and view my list. Does anyone have some good examples or ideas of this, or some links to places that utilize this very well? Also, is there a name for this type of search?

Answer (score 1):

SlickDeals.net has a "Deal Alert" system that's very similar to what you're describing.  Users can watch certain keywords or item categories and receive notifications when new deals are posted in the forums that match their criteria.  Here's a screenshot of the input form when configuring an alert:

[image: Setting up a new Alert on SlickDeals.net]

Google Alerts is another example where users can be notified when new content appears on the web that matches specific topics or keywords.

LexisNexis and other large online databases implement saved searches and email alert systems.  Here's [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbFjV91YNNY) demonstrating how to set up an alert at the National Center for Biotechnology Information that may give you some ideas.

I'm not sure of a single name for this type of search, but it could probably be referred to as an alert or subscription, and could be worded in such a way as, "Receive updates when new items are added," or, "Alert me of new search results."

Answer (score 0):

Use tag based search where each tags make a query and multiple tags can be combined to refine the search results example:Pintrest.
Then have two CTA search and save search .
Search - gets instant results
Save Search - Saves the query and gets updates regularly give an options to turn notification on. By default keep notification Off.
I think this is what you were asking for .. If not please leave a comment.cheers